# How to pass all props to a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I designed the below button using TailwindCSS with onClick event.

```
<button className="border bg-purple-600 rounded-lg text-white px-2 py-1 mb-4" onClick={handleClick}>
  Add Item
</button>
```

Now I tried creating a React component for this button. I want to use this component everywhere and sometimes it will have onClick prop, sometimes onMouseDown, etc. So I am trying to set whatever props are passed to my component on the button element inside the component. I came up with below.

```
function Button({
  children,
  ...props
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  props?: any;
}) {
  return (
    <button
      className="border bg-purple-600 rounded-lg text-white px-2 py-1 mb-4"
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

I did not know what to set the type of props so I've set it to `any` for now. This code does not show any errors.

But when I try to use the component as below, it says: `Type '{ children: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: ReactNode; props?: any; }'`

```
<Button onClick={handleClick}>
   Add Item
</Button>
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```ts
> {
>   children: React.ReactNode;
>   props?: any; //  this is incorrect
> }
> ```

Your component does't accept a `props` property. Instead, you're spreading the rest of the props. This means the above type definition won't match what you're passing to it.

Given you're just creating a button wrapper, you can use its default attributes (which already includes `children`).

```ts
import type { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from "react";

function Button({
  children,
  ...props
}: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>) {
  // ...
}
```

You might also want to prevent consumers passing in a `className` which would overwrite your own classes.

You could either just add yours after...

```html
<button
  {...props}
  className="border bg-purple-600 rounded-lg text-white px-2 py-1 mb-4"
>
  {children}
</button>
```

or expressly forbid it in the prop type

```ts
type ButtonProps = Omit<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, "className">;

function Button({
  children,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button
      className="border bg-purple-600 rounded-lg text-white px-2 py-1 mb-4"
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```